# Select columns based on the current column selected (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

**QUERY 1**

```
WITH CUST1 AS
(SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, TYPE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CONDITION),
    CARS1 AS
(SELECT * FROM CARS INNER JOIN CUST1 ON
    CUST1.CUSTOMER_ID = CARS.CUSTOMER_ID AND
    CUST1.TYPE = CARS.TYPE) select * from CARS1;
```

**CUSTOMERE TABLE**

```
    CUSTOMER_ID ||    TYPE        
    ------------||  -------       
    1           ||     5          
    2           ||     5          
    3           ||     2          
    4           ||     2
```

**CARS TABLE**

```
CAR_ID  ||  CUSTOMER_ID  ||   TYPE   ||   SN   ||  DATE                                      
------- ||  ------------ ||   ------ ||  ----- || -------
1       ||  1            ||    5     ||  0123  ||  02/06/1999
2       ||  1            ||    2     ||  2365  ||  03/08/1999             
3       ||  1            ||    3     ||  5156  ||  03/02/1999       
4       ||  3            ||    1     ||  8651  ||  03/03/1999       
5       ||  2            ||    5     ||  2555  ||  03/09/1999       
6       ||  2            ||    2     ||  8562  ||  03/18/1999
```

**QUERY 1 result**

```
CAR_ID  ||  CUSTOMER_ID  ||   TYPE   || SN    ||  DATE      
------- ||  ------------ ||  ------  || ----- || --------  
1       ||    1          ||     5    || 0123  || 02/06/1999
5       ||    2          ||     5    || 2555  || 03/09/1999
```

The above query joins the temp table "CUST1" with an actual table "CARS" on the columns `CUSTOMER_ID` and `TYPE`.
Now, what I am hoping to achieve is to select the DATE AS DATE2 and SN AS SN2 from CARS which belong to the customer where 
the CARS.TYPE = 2 for CUSTOMER_IDs resulted from the JOIN condition.

However, the dilemma is that I don't want to rejoin/use a sub-query since the CARS table is very big.
Please ignore the temp table approach as it's used in the rest of the code for other reasons. 
The current column would be CUSTOMER_ID and the other two columns based on that CUSTOMER_ID will be SN and TYPE.

Expected results

```
CAR_ID  ||   CUSTOMER_ID  ||   TYPE  || SN    ||  DATE      || DATE2       ||  SN2
------- ||   ------------ ||  ------ || ----- || --------   || -------     || -----
1       ||      1         ||     5   || 0123  || 02/06/1999 || 03/08/1999  ||  2365
5       ||      2         ||     5   || 2555  || 03/09/1999 || 03/18/1999  ||  8562
```

Comment: are you sure about `Query 1`? The Syntax is Incorrect.

Comment: Yes, look at CUST1 as the driving table and CARS1 as a query that selects based on the first query's reults.

Comment: So you basically want data from two different rows in CARS for every one row in CUSTOMERS, but without joining CARS more than once?  That could be a problem...

Comment: Will you have at most two rows for each customer in the table (view, subquery, whatever) `customer`? Also, how did you decide the order of the columns - the columns for "type 5" before those for "type 2"? How many types are there in total? Perhaps this can be done with a single join (and `pivot`) but it depends on the answers to these questions, and perhaps more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can without a join back to cars. How big is you cars table? Using my simple test, I found that I was creating a bloom filter which might be efficient enough to make the query perform. Why not try it an see if you really have a problem? Perhaps post the execution plan. For example:

```
 select c.car_id, c.customer_id, c.type, c.sn, c.car_date, c2.sn, c2.car_date, c2.sn 
from cars c 
join cust cu 
on c.customer_id = cu.customer_id 
and c.type = cu.type 
join cars c2 
on c2.customer_id = cu.customer_id 
where c2.type = 2
```

gives

```
    CAR_ID CUSTOMER_ID       TYPE SN   CAR_DATE  SN   CAR_DATE  SN
---------- ----------- ---------- ---- --------- ---- --------- ----
         1           1          5 0123 06-FEB-99 2365 08-MAR-99 2365
         5           2          5 2555 09-MAR-99 8652 18-MAR-99 8652
```

.

```
select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'TYPICAL' ) );

----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name    | Rows  | Bytes |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |         |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                   |         |     2 |   234 |
|   2 |   JOIN FILTER CREATE         | :BF0000 |     2 |   130 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                 |         |     2 |   130 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CARS    |     2 |    78 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CUST    |     4 |   104 |
|   6 |   JOIN FILTER USE            | :BF0000 |     6 |   312 |
|*  7 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL | CARS    |     6 |   312 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional aggregation will do what you want.  I'm not sure what the actually logic is, but it seems to be along these lines:

```
SELECT CAR_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, 5 as TYPE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 5 THEN SN END) as SN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 5 THEN DATE END) as DATE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 2 THEN SN END) as SN2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE = 2 THEN DATE END) as DATE2,
 CARS c INNER JOIN CUST1 cu
     ON cu.CUSTOMER_ID = c.CUSTOMER_ID AND
        cu.TYPE = c.TYPE
WHERE CONDITION
GROUP BY CAR_ID, CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Comment: It seems pretty clear from the question, its title, and the posted sample data that the types "5" and "2" need to be read from the `customer` table - they are not fixed numbers.